# Does a variance decomposition make sense with a non-linear link function?

Tags: r, bayesian, variance, hierarchical-bayesian

I am doing a variance decomposition, with a hierarchal random intercept model like the one below (BRMS R Code):

```
model <- brm(DV ~ (1 | Level_1) + (1|Level_1:Level_2) +(1|Level_1:Level_2:Level_3)
```

Where I measure the effect size of every level in terms of the variance explained of the random intercept coefficients on that level.

I know that technically, it is possible to change the link function, but wonder whether it makes sense in the context of a variance decomposition. My main concern is that, after introducing a non-linear link function the variance decomposition (i.e. the variance explained of the coefficients on each level) “explains” the effect sizes in terms of the non-linearly transformed Dependent Variable (DV) and the variance in terms of the original DV cannot be recovered.
Is my understanding correct or is there a way to do variance decomposition with a non-linear link function and nevertheless correctly recover the variances explained by the coefficients for the original DV?